# Boolean expressions from multiplication to addition and vice-versa

Tags: boolean-algebra

I am trying to change these Boolean expressions into expressions that do not use multiplication. Bolds indicate complements.

a) abc

b) (ab +**c**)d

And these to ones that do not use addition.

c) a + b + c

d) (ab + **c**)d + **e**

How should I approach these problems?

Comment: So multiplication is "AND" and addition "OR"?

Comment: That is correct!

Comment: And complements are "NOT AND" or "NOT OR"?

Comment: The opposite of whatever the initial input was. A one becomes a zero or a zero becomes  a one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $a\wedge b$ is the same as $\neg(\neg a \vee \neg b)$.  Wherever you have multiplication, just apply this rule...  You can similarly remove + with the rule $a\vee b = \neg(\neg a \wedge \neg b)$.  If you think about what these statements say, you can see why they are true.

Comment: Thank you, will use this tip when I get back to this later tonight.